# avoid duplication of table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, schema

I have table with data about tasks like Id, Name, Date, WorkerId, VehicleId (and more 50 fields).

I would like to build orders module that will aloow users insert tasks as an order.
An order contains subset fields from task, for example WorkerId and VehicleId only (as I said - there are more then 50 fields in tasks table).
Since each user can choose his fields definition that compose an order - I have to duplicate the tasks table and name it orders table.
Because the huge size (in terms of fields) of tasks table, I want to avoid duplicate it. Is there any possible way to store order data that not include create huge table like tasks table?

P.S. I don't want to store the orders in tasks table because:
1. there will be many orders that might affect performance.
2. there are many many tasks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure from your description, but it sounds like you want to treat the columns from the table "tasks" as line items of an order.

```
ord_num  line_item    task_attribute    attribute_value
--
15       1            WorkerId          35
15       2            VehicleId         101-345-2A3574
```

Having said that, though, I have to say that

- it does make sense to me to let users
  order tasks, but
- it doesn't make sense to me to let
  users order one or two columns from a
  table of tasks.

Especially to just order one or two id numbers from a table of tasks--WTF does that *mean*, anyway?

Comment: It is very duplicate system with many connections and I tried to make things really simple so it sound like it is not logical. But trust me - it is. The problem with your solution is that I cannot use foreign keys and I think this is a huge minus.

Comment: @Naor: If you have to set foreign keys to the "tasks" table, you can't let the user pick columns, can you? A foreign key has to reference either a primary key, or a column or set of columns that has a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field `is_order` to your tasks table and set this to true if its an order or false if its a task.

You may also want to rename your table to show that it can contain either orders or tasks.

Comment: I updated my question - I don't want to combine tasks and orders.

Comment: I have many many reasons why not to do it and I can write many stories and waste a lot of time. I don't want to cimbine tables - please try to help me with my restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to create a new table, but you don't want it to have 50+ columns. Is that right?

You could do something like `Orders(ID, Configuration)` where Configuration is some string representation of all the optional data. Or you could do something like `Orders(ID, FieldID, FieldValue)`. In this case, if an order had three of the optional fields, it would show up as 3 different rows in the table. Both approaches create challenges when you want to query them. I think I would bite the bullet and just have the 50 column table.

Comment: Please see the comment I add to Catcall's answer which is similar to yours.

Comment: If FK's are important, then I think you need the 50 column table even more.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 50 fields in Task, that table is un-normalised.  If it is a "very duplicate system", the database is not Normalised.  As you seem to be aware, un-normalised tables are difficult to extend, they place severe restrictions on functional extension.

Before you add Order, and relate them to Tasks or components of Task, thereby compounding the duplication, you need to Normalise Task first.  That will result in several normalised tables (Person, Vehicle, Worker) which Task relates to, and it will then be simple to add Order and relate Order to those tables.

Comment: My table is normalized and I have already Workers, Vehicles and so on tables.

Comment: @Naor. That is great.  In that case, post the DDL of all tables related to Task (incl indices).  We can relate Order to the appropriate tables, rather than to Task.